# Dynamic Table INNER JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, database

Okay.. this is the most updated information here.
    I need to generate comments for each ID as they increment. I.E 
    I have  customer 1. he/ she signs up and then I have the ability to work on their account for whatever I am doing with it.. I need to leave comments on that particular page. " THAT I CAN DO "
    A second customer signs up, then on the link for user 2 I can access their account and leave comments for admin purposes only..

"THIS I CAN NOT DO BECAUSE IN THE INSERT I AM ONLY POINTING AT ID # 1.. I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO POINT AT A NEW ID "

3rd customer signs up... and so on and so on..
  The code is below. I have included all the PHP code here also.. you can test it on your end with your own data connection.

```
/* CREATING THE TABLE Customers*/
      <?php
include('../includes/mysql_connect.php');
$query = "CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
`customer_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cust_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
INDEX (`customer_id`),
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
)engine=innodb";
if(@mysql_query($query,$dbc)){
echo '<p>Table for customers has been successfully created!</p><br/>';
} else {
echo '' . mysql_error($dbc)  .'<br/>';
}
mysql_close($dbc);
?>


/* CREATING THE TABLE Comments*/
<?php 
include('../includes/mysql_connect.php');
$query = "CREATE TABLE `Comments` (
`comment_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customer_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`comment` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`comment_id`),
INDEX (`customer_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `Customers`
(`customer_id`)
)engine=innodb";

if(@mysql_query($query,$dbc)){
echo '<p>Table for Comments has been successfully created!</p><br/>';
} else {
echo '' . mysql_error($dbc)  .'<br/>';
}
mysql_close($dbc);
?>

/* So now that I have already created the tables, I work on getting the link for each customer. */

<?php
include('includes/mysql_connect.php');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `Customers` ';
if($y = mysql_query($query,$dbc)){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($y)){
//echo " {$row['id']} <br/>";

echo "<div id='container'>
<div id='first_wrapper'>
<a style='text-decoration:none'; href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/master/account.php?id={$row['customer_id']}\"> 
Customer # " . $row['customer_id'] ." 
</a></div>";
}
}
mysql_close($dbc);
?>


/* The next step is to retrieve the info From the Customers table */
/* Select records for specific user based upon their ID */
<?php

include('includes/mysql_connect.php');

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { 

$query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE `customer_id`={$_GET['id']}";
if($x = mysql_query($query,$dbc)){

$row = mysql_fetch_array($x); 

echo "{$row['cust_name']}<br/>";

echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '"/>';    
}
}
mysql_close($dbc);  

?>

/* My problem comes here on the comments table */


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
// NEEDS DATA CONNECTION
include('includes/mysql_connect.php');
// VARIABLE IF PROBLEM DOES NOT OCCUR
$problem = FALSE;
// VALIDATION HERE
if(!empty($_POST['comment'])){

$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment'])), $dbc);
} else { // IF PROBLEM
echo '<p style="color:red;">Please enter comment!</p>';
$problem = TRUE;
}
//IF NO PROBLEM
if(!$problem){

// RUN QUERY

$query = "INSERT INTO `Comments`(`customer_id`,`comment`) VALUES (1,'$comment')";
// EXECUTE QUERY
if(@mysql_query($query,$dbc)){
echo '<p style="color:blue;">This comment has been added!<p>';
} else {// IF PROBLEM
echo '<p style="color:red;">Could not retrieve the information because <br/> 
'. mysql_error($dbc) .'.</p><p>The query run was '.$query.' </p>';
}
} // END OF VARIABLE IN NO PROBLEM
mysql_close($dbc); // CLOSING CONNECTION
} // END OF MAIN IF
?>
<html>
<head><title>DUMMY INSERTS</title></head>
<body>
<form action="self.php" method="post">
<textarea name="comment" cols="70" rows="10"/></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PLEASE HELP ME OUT ON THIS ONE.. I HAVE BEEN ALREADY A WEEK ON THIS AND I AM TIRED.. THX

Comment: I am missing the exact problem here. Do you want to migrate data or need php code or if your association is correct?

Comment: You are not inserting a `customers_id` in `INSERT INTO \`comments\` (\`comment\`) values ('$comment')`, so you are going to get a `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: it will not allow you to enter because you told it not to. You need to have a customer_id when inserting records (rows) I think you need more logic. Please provide all your php code as this can't be everything

Comment: You need to specify the `customers_id`, either from a session variable, or an id input from your comment form, or from somewhere else. How do you know which customer  the comment is about?

Comment: Are you entering the comment at the same time that you are entering the customer into `customers`. Or are you added the comment at a later time?

Comment: Well if it is at the same time, you would use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) on the `customers` table, and insert that into the `comments` table. If it is at a latter time, you would need to get the `customer_id` from the `customers` table before inserting.

Comment: [SQLFiddle with working code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eaa1/1)

Comment: Please Show the PHP code that executes those queries. These are just the variables containing the queries. Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: @philipxy... I need your help.. let me ask you a question.. I have made sure I have created the right tables and with the right index and foreing key.. I will update you tomorrow and I'll update my code above... but my question is... when i do insert into `Comments`(`cust_id`,`comment`) VALUES (1,'$comment')";     I will always be pointing at customer ID number 1....  Remember that my goal is to have a commenting system for each customer as they automatically increment.. so what do I need to do so that every time a new customer signs up.. my comments don't pull only user ID 1

Comment: @philipxy wish there was a way just to call u man lol

Comment: @sean.. I can't do Last_insert_id() because I get an error message with the foreign key failing..  only when I put the value as 1 then I'm allowed to insert info.. but with that you suggested is not allowing me to enter comments.. so it can't be it

Comment: It's 3 am here in the east coast.. I'll check back later on and see what you guys say.. ttyl

Comment: Will do tomorrow.. I need to get this done.. total priority

Comment: @philipxy I have updated my code with everything I have to make it work.. You can test it on your IDE.. just add your data connection and you will see my issue.. I can only point at user ID 1.. I can't point at the next users ID. As I had explain before.. I need to leave comments on each ID / account but then I try to leave comments on ID 2.. it points only at I one.

Comment: @Sean I have updated my code above.. thx

Comment: You need to add the `echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '"/>'; ` to inside your form - `<form action="self.php" method="post">`. Then when you post the form use the `$_GET['id']` value in your `INSERT` query instead of the `1`.

Comment: Well.. I sent you everything I got... srry tho @philipxy

Comment: @philipxy I guess my php isn't good enough based on what you are saying.. well I am self taught.. I am doing my best here.

Comment: Good: php. Now please go to a site like [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and make a working example that you edit into your question.

Comment: No, It's your job as asker, as the Help Center (especially re MCVE) (which you should have read and should read now and act upon) tells you, you should do this for every question regarding code behaviour.

Comment: @Sean I can't add the {$_GET['id']} on the insert query.. issue with syntax I am trying to correct.. I have the feeling that you sent me will work

Comment: yeah I know it is customer_id... I am trying...

Answer (score 0):

Per davejal's comment: The FK constraint says *every value in comments customers_id must be a value in customers customers_id*.

So Sean said: First `INSERT INTO customers (cust_name) values ('$cust_name')` which uses customers' AUTO_INCREMENT for customers_id. Then `INSERT INTO comments (customers_id, comment) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$comment')` which uses LAST_INSERT_ID for the customers customers_id value chosen by that AUTO_INCREMENT and comments' AUTO_INCREMENT for comments_id.

Per Sean & philipxy: The customer insert AUTO_INCREMENT makes you a new customer id. If you want it right away then use LAST_INSERT_ID(); otherwise you get their id when they sign in or admin gives it. Per Ryan Vincent's sqlfiddle: [A version modified to use LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/124e5/1).

Per Sean & Ryan Vincent: As you are using PHP for i/o show it in your question. If you GET a customer id whose comments you want to process (`echo '<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="' . $_GET['customer_id'] . '"/>';`) inside your form) then *that* is the value to use in your comment INSERT or SELECT via `$_GET['customer_id']`.

All such minimal fiddled code, input, output (possibly including debug output during execution, although that can affect the manifestation of a bug) and error(s) should be in every question about fixing code. Read and act on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: 1st insert works good. second insert won't go through no matter what  ..   I have tried all the possible ways and it is just not taking the query..          $query = "INSERT INTO `comments`(`comment`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$comment')";                                                             $query = "INSERT INTO `comments` VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$comment')";                                                           $query = "INSERT INTO `comments`(`customer_id`,`comment`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$comment')";   this became a thing I will never let go until I understand it

Comment: i get this even when I add the FK                                                           Could not retrieve the information because 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_database`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customers_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customers_id`)).

The query run was INSERT INTO `comments`(`customers_id`,`comment`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test')

Comment: Also, it helps to clean up comments when the dust settles.

Comment: U awesome man.. the only one that knows php around me is... me.. so when I get stuck I have no one to get me out.. that's how I got here just a few days ago